# image is being corrupted when uploaded to flutter web

Tags: flutter-web

I've been trying to upload an image in flutter web app.I am getting a 200 response code when I upload the image but the problem is the image I uploaded turned up to be corrupted. I have searched for posts similar to mine but I couldn't resolve the issue. I tried using http.Multipart and dio package but both are giving me the same result. Basically what I'm trying to do is pick the image from computer disk using (tried using FilePicer.platform.pickfiles and ImagePickerWeb.getImageInfo) and uplaod it to the server.

I really really need help with this
I need answer for that

Why is nobody answering this??

This is the image picker method using ImagePickerWeb

```
pickProfileImageWeb() async {
    MediaInfo mediaInfo = await ImagePickerWeb.getImageInfo;
            if (mediaInfo != null) {
              setState(() {
                imagevalue = mediaInfo.data!;
              });
            }
            print("mediaInfo is ${mediaInfo.fileName}");

              uploadImageWeb(mediaInfo.data!, mediaInfo.fileName!);
    
               imageUploadWithHttp(mediaInfo.data!);
    }
```

Using FilePicker.platform.pickFiles

```
pickProfileImageWeb() async {
    FilePickerResult? imagePicked = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
    
        if (imagePicked != null) {
          Uint8List? fileBytes = imagePicked.files.first.bytes;
    
          String fileName = imagePicked.files.first.name;

   
    
          setState(() {
            imagevalue = fileBytes!;
          });
    
          print("Image name is $fileName");
    
           uploadImageWeb(fileBytes!, fileName);

           imageUploadWithHttp(fileBytes, fileName);
    }
```

And here are my uploaders using both dio and http.Multipart

```
uploadImageWeb(Uint8List fileBytes, String? fileName) async {
    var dioo = Dio();

    try {
      final Map<String, String> header = {
        // "file-name": fileName!,
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Authorization": "Bearer",
      };

      dio.FormData formData = dio.FormData.fromMap(
        {
          "image": dio.MultipartFile.fromBytes(fileBytes),
          "content-type": lookupMimeType(fileBytes.toString())
        },
      );
      String? sUrl = await _profileController.getSignedUrl("profile");

      print("Singed url is $sUrl");

      if (sUrl != null) {
        var response = await dioo.put(
          Uri.parse(sUrl).toString(),
          data: formData,
        );

        _profileController.isPicUploading(true);

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          print("The response is ${response.statusCode}");
        } else {
          print("Error when uploading files ${response.statusCode}");
          _profileController.isPicUploading(false);
        }
      } else {
        print("Signed Url is null $sUrl");
      }
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print("Error is $e");
    }
}
```

Using http.Multipart

```
imageUploadWithHttp(Uint8List? filepath, String? fileName) async {
    try {
      String? sUrl;

      sUrl = await _profileController.getSignedUrl("profile").then(
        (signedUrl) async {
          print("singedUrl is $signedUrl");
          final Map<String, String> header = {
            "file-name": fileName!,
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
          };

          print("Sined url is $signedUrl");

          if (signedUrl != null) {
            var request = http.MultipartRequest(
              "PUT",
              Uri.parse(signedUrl),
            );
            request.headers.addAll(header);

            request.files.add(
              http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
                "file",
                List.from(filepath!),
                contentType: MediaType("application", 'octet-stream'),
              ),
            );

            _profileController.isPicUploading(true);

            request.send().then((response) {
              if (response == 200) {
                print("Uploaded!");
              } else {
                print("Error when uploading files ${response.statusCode}");
              }
              _profileController.isPicUploading(false);
            });
          }
        },
      );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print("error is $e");
      _profileController.isPicUploading(false);
    }
  }
}
```

In both cases I got this.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you dont give filename to multipart request. Try to give proper file name to your multipart request.
For example:

```
newFormData.files.add(MapEntry(
   mapFile.key,
              apiDio.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
                _selectedFile,
                filename: 'file_up.jpg',
                contentType: new MediaType('image', 'jpg'),
              )));
```